# MVVM Binding DataGrid to one Object in List<Object>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I have a `ObservableCollection<object>`.  Each object has a list of properties that are displayed in the datagrid.  One object should be displayed in the datagrid at a time.  The user then modifies property values within the datagrid.  The user should be able to choose which object is displayed in the datagrid using a combobox.

I don't know how to have the DataGrid have a binding with the original `ObservableCollection<object>`.  My current solution is to have a standalone object with a binding to the ComboBox's SelectedItem, and the DataGrid is bound to that object.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ifcCombo" 
            DisplayMemberPath="ifcEntity"
            SelectedItem="{Binding chosenConcept}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ConceptList}"/>

<DataGrid x:Name="propertiesTable"
          ItemsSource="{Binding chosenConcept.propertyList}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mapping}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This can't be the best way to do this.  Although I do have a working binding on my DataGrid.  Now, in my ViewModel, I have an object that needs to manually replace an object that is in the original `ObservableCollection<object>`.  So I can do a Linq query, and replace that object, but I feel there must be a more proper way to do this binding.

```
private ObservableCollection<EntityConcept> _ConceptList = new ObservableCollection<EntityConcept>();
private EntityConcept _chosenConcept = new EntityConcept();
```

To provide some more context.  I will show the object(class) for EntityConcept that I am talking about:

```
public class EntityConcept
    {
        private ObservableCollection<PropertyItem> _propertyList;
        private string _ifcEntity;

        public ObservableCollection<PropertyItem> propertyList
        {
            get
            {
                return _propertyList;
            }
            set
            {
                _propertyList = value;
            }
        }             
        public string ifcEntity
        {
            get
            {
                return _ifcEntity;
            }
            set
            {
                _ifcEntity = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The PropertyItem class is an object with many properties, but they are all primitives.

Also, you get bonus points if your solution will work with a ListCollectionView, because I eventually want to display this information in groups.

Comment: Why do you want to use `DataGrid` when you have single object? You can use other content presenter control to display the single object

Comment: I will update the post.  Its because I am trying to display a list of properties that exist within that object.

Comment: Then if its list of properties then its collection not the single object. Correct?

Comment: Correct, I want to display a collection of objects that each has a collection of primitive properties.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a standalone object with a binding to the ComboBox's SelectedItem. Bind to the selected property directly in the XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ifcCombo" 
            DisplayMemberPath="ifcEntity"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ConceptList}"/>

<DataGrid x:Name="propertiesTable" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ifcCombo, Path=SelectedItem}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding propertyList}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mapping}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Also add `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` in order to prevent generating the columns twice.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you also want to do something with the chosen Concept

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ifcCombo" 
          DisplayMemberPath="ifcEntity"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ConceptList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ChosenConcept}"/>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="propertyListCollection" Source="{Binding ChosenConcept.propertyList}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Foo"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource propertyListCollection}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mapping}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```